# Carry Hidden Value To Next HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, input, hidden-field

If I had three html pages - on the first one I have a hidden value of 1 `<input type="hidden" value="1" />`, a second random html page and a third html page where I need to display the hidden value from the first form.

How would I be able to get the hidden value across to the third page and display it? I need to get through the second page first to get to the third page. Is there a way to achieve this with HTML only or would I need to use JavaScript to retrieve the hidden parameter?

Hope I make sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Querystrings` or `cookies`.
i would prefer `cookies`
Check this link

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp